# List of Symbols don't show inputs

Tags: tocloft

I'm using the `tocloft` package to create a list of symbols. But the inputs that I want to appear in the list just don't show up in it. Here's a MWE of my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listofsymbs}{List of Symbols}
\newlistof[chapter]{symbols}{sym}{\listofsymbs}

\newcommand{\symb}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{symbols}%
    #1%
    \addcontentsline{sym}{symbols}{\protect\numberline{\thesymbols}#1}}

\begin{document}

\listofsymbs

The generation of electric energy by photovoltaic network distributed in Asgard has greatly increased in recent years. Between 1995 and 2009, 39 photovoltaic systems connected to the grid were installed in Asgard, of which 35 were in operation in 2009, totaling an operating power of 161.32 \symb{kWp}

\end{document}
```

All I get is the title `List of Symbols` but none of the symbols I want to add on it.

[image]

Comment: You create the list using `\listofsymbols`,  `\listofsymbs` is just the title used, same as `\contentsname`.  Don't forget to run it twice.

Comment: Is there a way of instead of showing the page number referred to the input, actually show the label or caption?

Comment: Replacing the page number would me nearly impossible, due to the way `\protected@write` works.  You would be better off using the glossaries package.